# Delphi integration

Tags: api, integrate

Delphi integration. 
Hi, does anyone already have a working Delphi to magento API integration - preferably using SOAP, and downloading into Delphi ClientDataset? 
If so, is it possible for me to obtain some source code for delphi, and some instructions for what is needed on the magento web site.